# insert dynamic text "google ads" on a asp.net repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-2.0, repeater, datarepeater

I want to insert Google ads on a asp.net repeater on the 3rd iteration. 
I'm trying to figure out how to do this, here is what I have.

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
            <HeaderTemplate>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="Pl">
                 <%# int i=0; if(i!=3){ %>
                        <div class="PlFoto">
                            //display content  
                        </div>
                 <%# ++i;} else {%>
                          //display Google ads
                 <%# ++i;}%>
                </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <% int i = 0;%>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="Pl">
        <%  if (i != 3) { %>
            <div class="PlFoto"></div>
        <% ++i;}else{ %>
            <div class="ads"></div>
        <% ++i;   } %>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will "i" ever be equal to 3?  Won't the "int i=0;" be executed with each iteration?  Try putting that declaration outside the repeater and see if it works better.

Comment: <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
            <HeaderTemplate>
<% int i=0;%>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="Pl">
                 <%  if(i!=3){ %>
                        <div class="PlFoto">
                            //display content  
                        </div>
                 <% ++i;} else {%>
                          //display Google ads
                 <% ++i;}%>
                </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

Comment: Nope, HeaderTemplate is only executed once.

Comment: @Djuro: HeaderTemplate *should* only be executed once.  There's only one header row.

Comment: @David why "should"? Header template is executed only once, and you cant make it execute more times.

Comment: @Djuro: Because a header occurs once, at the top of the grid.  That's what a header *is*.  What exactly are you trying to do and what does it have to do with this *ancient* and barely useful Stack Overflow question?  If you have a question to ask, ask it in its own question.

Comment: @David oh, sorry, dont know why this question popped up to me, i thought it is a new one, i didnt notice that is really ancient question :)